# python 2.7.9 backport to trusty (14.04)

Tags: python, gcc, launchpad, backport

I try to backport **Python 2.7.9** from **vivid** to **trusty** but when launchpad build this pakage there is an build error.

I create my backport :

```
backportpackage -d trusty -u ppa:splanquart/python http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.9-1.dsc
```

I take an error in bottom of buildlog :

```
...
running python rtupdate hooks for python3.4...
running python post-rtupdate hooks for python3.4...
Setting up lsb-release (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.4) ...
Checking correctness of source dependencies...
After installing, the following source dependencies are still unsatisfied:
dpkg-dev(inst 1.17.5ubuntu5.3 ! >= wanted 1.17.11) gcc(inst 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 ! >= wanted >4:4.9.2-1~) gcc-4.9(missing)
Source-dependencies not satisfied; skipping python2.7
******************************************************************************
Finished at 20150108-1652
...
```

How can I solve this issue?

I search to downgrade the dependencies version for gcc and for dpkg-dev without success. 
For that I clear all and ...
I download package by :

```
backportpackage -d trusty --dont-sign -w . http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7_2.7.9-1.dsc
```

I change version in **Build-Depends** in *python2.7_2.7.9-1~ubuntu14.04.1.dsc* :

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 5), dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.5), gcc (>= 4:4.8.2), quilt, autoconf, autotools-dev, lsb-release, sharutils, libreadline-dev, libtinfo-dev, libncursesw5-dev (>= 5.3), tk-dev, blt-dev (>= 2.4z), libssl-dev, zlib1g-dev, libbz2-dev, libexpat1-dev, libbluetooth-dev [linux-any], locales [!armel !avr32 !hppa !ia64 !mipsel], libsqlite3-dev, libffi-dev (>= 3.0.5) [!or1k !avr32], libgpm2 [linux-any], mime-support, netbase, net-tools, bzip2, libdb-dev (<< 1:6.0), libgdbm-dev, python:any, help2man, xvfb, xauth
```

And after I upload to launchpad by :

```
backportpackage -u  ppa:splanquart/python python2.7_2.7.9-1~ubuntu14.04.1.dsc
```

But I also get the same error :

```
...
running python post-rtupdate hooks for python3.4...
Setting up lsb-release (4.1+Debian11ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.4) ...
Checking correctness of source dependencies...
After installing, the following source dependencies are still unsatisfied:
dpkg-dev(inst 1.17.5ubuntu5.3 ! >= wanted 1.17.11) gcc(inst 4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6 ! >= wanted 4:4.9.2-1~) gcc-4.9(missing)
Source-dependencies not satisfied; skipping python2.7
******************************************************************************
Finished at 20150109-1640
...
```

Comment: Instead of using `backportpackage` the second time around, can you instead verify that the top of `debian/changelog` is for Trusty and instead use `dpkg-buildpackage -S -sa` and `dput`?

Answer (score 1):

[ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes-python2.7) is the latest version of python2.7

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It will upgrade python to 2.7.10

Comment: I don't know that this answers the question asked, but this is a very useful tip.  It never occurred to me to use the deadsnakes repo to get a *newer* version of python, but this works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `dpkg-dev` and `gcc` packages aren't up to date enough for the build process.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc4.9
sudo apt-get upgrade dpkg-dev
```

And then do your `backportpackage` again to see if it's any better. As it looks like that build process is looking for gcc 4.9, thus the second command

Comment: The build is done in launchpad, therefore if I upgrade my gcc and my dpkg-dev there is not action on build do on launchpad architecture. There is something that I forgot?